# backbone.js removing template from DOM upon success

Tags: javascript, dom, backbone.js

I'm writing  a simple message board app to learn backbone. It's going ok (a lot of the use of this isn't making sense) but am a little stuck in terms of how I would remove a form  / html from the dom. I have included most of the code but you can see about 4 lines up from the bottom, the part that isn't working. How would I remove this from the DOM?

thx in advance

```
var MbForm=Backbone.View.extend({
  events: {
  'click button.add-new-post': 'savePost'
  },

  el: $('#detail'),
  template:_.template($('#post-add-edit-tmpl').html()),
  render: function(){
    var compiled_template = this.template();
    this.$el.html(compiled_template);
    return this;
  },
  savePost: function(e){
    //var self=this;
    //console.log("I want you to say Hello!");
    data={
     header: $('#post_header').val(),
     detail: $('#post_detail').val(),
     forum_id: $('#forum_id').val(),
     post_id: $('#post_id').val(),
     parent_id: $('#parent_id').val()
    };

    this.model.save(data, {
      success: function(){
        alert('this saved');
        //$(this.el).html('this is what i want');
        this.$el.remove();//  <- this is the part that isn't working


       /* none of these worked - error Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'unbind' of undefined 
        this.$el.unbind();
        this.$el.empty();

        this.el.unbind();
        this.el.empty();
       */

        //this.unbind();
        //self.append('this is appended');
      }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Backbone doesn't call the `success` callback with any particular `this`, it is simply called as a plain function. So, `this` inside your `success` callback will be `window` rather than the view you're expecting it to be.

Any of the usual solutions will work:

1. Save the desired `this` in a local variable:

   ```
   var _this = this;
   this.model.save(data, {
     success: function() {
       //...
       _this.remove();
   ```
2. Use a bound function:

   ```
   this.model.save(data, {
     success: _(function() {
       //...
       this.remove();
     }).bind(this)
   ```
3. Use a named bound function:

   ```
   initialize: function() {
       _.bindAll(this, 'save_success');
   }
   //...
   this.model.save(data, {
     success: this.save_success
   ```

And the usual variations on the above.

Also note that I switched to [`View#remove`](http://backbonejs.org/#View-remove) since you are apparently trying to remove the whole view and that's the usual way to do it.

Comment: thx - let me test through these; quick follow-up question: I could just clear this out via jQuery but I assume that that is not used (or looks like it isn't used). Is that too ugly to use? I'd like to get something working and if I have to go clean up later, that's ok. thx again for answer

Comment: @timpone: You could just `this.$el.remove()` (that's what [`View#remove`](http://backbonejs.org/#View-remove) does by default anyway) but using `this.remove()` allows you to add other cleanup stuff (such as unbinding from model events) in a `remove` override.

Comment: ok thx -  I tried this.$el.remove() like every way; I must have some other error. Let me see if I can get this working in a fiddle